# Web Scraping haciendo uso de Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, scraping

He intentado obtener el tipo de cambio de dólar a mi moneda local, al no tener una API a mi disposición quisiera hacer un scraping de un sitio web de un banco local que muestra estos datos.

Gracias a la recomendación de una de las respuestas de esta pregunta en ingles he dado con la librería [Simple HTML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813273/web-scraping-in-php) siguiendo la documentación es una libreria bastante simple de usar.

**Problema:**

El sitio web desde donde quiero obtener los datos es un sitio bastante simple [Sitio Source](https://www.banpais.hn/barradolar.php); el único detalle es que la información está dentro de un único `DIV` y quisiera obtener los valores de **Compra** y **Venta** por separado, para guardar cada uno de los valores en una variable, ¿es esto posible?

```
...<div class="conteTasa">Compra: <b>24.0199</b> <br>Venta: <b>24.1880</b></div>...
```

**Lo que he intentado:**

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$htmlsite = file_get_html('https://www.banpais.hn/barradolar.php');

$element = $htmlsite->find('div[class="conteTasa"]',0);

echo $element;

?>
```

> Compra: 24.0199 Venta: 24.1880

Pero como se puede dar cuenta, obtengo como respuesta todo el div completo.

Agradeceria cualquier comentario,

Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si `$element` contiene esto:

```
Compra: <b>24.0199</b> <br>Venta: <b>24.1880</b>
```

Puedes usar [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php) para eliminar las etiquetas HTML, eliminar las palabras y dejar solo los importes con [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) y, finalmente, separar con [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

```
$element = strip_tags($element);
// Resultado: Compra: 24.0199 Venta: 24.1880

// Eliminar palabras y dejar solo importes
$element = str_replace(['Compra: ', 'Venta: '], '', $element);
// Resultado: 24.0199 24.1880

$importes = explode(' ', $element);
// Resultado: ["24.0199", "24.1880"]

// Ya puedes acceder a los valores
$compra = $importes[0];
$venta = $importes[1];
```

Por supuesto, todavía faltaría realizar alguna validación, como comprobar que `$importes` tiene dos elementos ([count()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count)) y que ambos son numéricos ([floatval()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.floatval))

Comment: Hola @Triby, muchas gracias, me ha funcionado a la perfeccion.

Answer (score 1):

No se si exista una mejor forma, pero puedes usar la función [explode](https://www.anerbarrena.com/php-explode-4656/#:~:text=Con%20PHP%20explode()%20podemos,similar%20es%3A%20PHP%20str_split().) de php para crear un array. por ejemplo

```
$element = $htmlsite->find('div[class="conteTasa"]',0);

$array = explode("<b>", $element);
```

El resultado

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Compra: "
  [1]=>
  string(23) "24.0199</b> <br>Venta: "
  [2]=>
  string(11) "24.1880</b>"
}
```

Entonces guardamos en variables el valor que retorne

```
$compra = $array['2'];
$venta = str_replace( '<br>Venta: ', '', $array['1'] );
```

Uso [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) para eliminar los valores que no necesite

Resultado

```
24.1880</b>
24.0199</b>
```

Limpiamos las etiquetas que quedan

```
echo strip_tags( $compra, '</b>' );
echo strip_tags( $venta, '</b>' );
```

Resultado

```
24.1880
24.0199
```

Comment: @Jefferson Bol, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la he probado y funciona tambien.